# How to get the world coordinates of a point in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glut, transformation

I draw 4 Link chain of line segments by using the following code. As shown in the image i need to get the coordinates of Points A,B,C,D.

[image: 4_Link_Chain]

I am trying to implement a basic CCD inverse kinematic and based on the mouse coordinates i want to move link A-D. The first step to do that is to obtain a vector between the target point and point C and between C-D. For that i need to know the coordinates of C,D at any given time. How can i do that?

```
#define NUM_LINKS 4
#define l1 80

void drawLine(int l)
  {
   glColor3f(1,1,0);
   glPointSize( 10.0 );
   glBegin( GL_POINTS);
         glVertex2f(0,0);
   glEnd();
   glBegin( GL_LINES);
         glVertex2f(0,0);
         glVertex2f(l,0);  // l= 80
   glEnd();

    }



  void drawArm()
    {


glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glPushMatrix();
for(int i =0 ; i<NUM_LINKS; i++)
 {

    glRotatef(rotAngle[i],0,0,1);
    drawLine(l1);
    glTranslatef(l1,0,0);

}
glPopMatrix();
    glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();

   }
```

Comment: Look into `glUnProject` in glu: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluUnProject.xml

Comment: I looked into that, it needs WinX,WinY,WinZ as its arguments, where do i get that from ? Nehes Tutorial: http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/using_gluunproject/16013/ does it by using the mouse click, I dont want to do that.

Comment: It doesn't look like you using view matrix, so your modelview would be actually only modeling. Modeling (or `world`, as directx calls it) transforms from object space to world space - which, as quesion states, is what you need. Just get resulting matrix with `glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)` and multiply `(l, 0, 0, 1)` vector by this matrix.

Comment: @DexteroidCN WinX and WinY are just the screen coordinates of the point. WinZ is a little more complicated.